# request for member ‘getSize’ in ‘l2’, which is of non-class type ‘List()’

Tags: c++, list, oop, constructor

i'm trying to implement a SingleLinked List class in C++ but I got this error in my code and I can't figure out why

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename Data>
class List{
protected:
    ulong size = 0;

    struct Node{
        Data value;
        struct Node *next = nullptr;

        Node(Data newValue){
            value = newValue;
        }
    };

    struct Node* top = nullptr;

public:
    //Default constructor
    List() =default;

    //Specific constructor
    List(ulong, Data);

    void printList() const;

    ulong getSize();
};

//Specific constructor
template <typename Data>
List<Data>::List(ulong newSize, Data value){
    size = newSize;
    struct Node* tmp;
    struct Node* tmp2 = nullptr;

    for(ulong i = 0; i < newSize; i++){
        tmp2 = new struct Node(value);
        if(top == nullptr){
            top = tmp2;
        }else{
            tmp = top;
            while(tmp->next != nullptr){
                tmp = tmp->next;
            }
            tmp->next = tmp2;
        }
    }
}

template <typename Data>
void List<Data>::printList() const{
    struct Node* tmp = top;
    while(tmp != nullptr){
        std::cout << tmp->value;
        if(tmp->next != nullptr)
            std::cout << " -> ";
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
    delete tmp;
}

template <typename Data>
ulong List<Data>::getSize(){
    return size;
}

int main(){
    List<int> l1(10,1);

    l1.printList();

    std::cout << l1.getSize() << std::endl;

    List<int> l2();

    std::cout << l2.getSize() << std::endl;


   return 0;
}
```

Everything works fine until I call l2.getSize()...it's like the compiler doesn't see l2 is a List object ; I also defined the default constructor in a different way (like List(){}) but I always get this error.

Thanks

Comment: Most vexing parse issue. Try `List<int> l2;`. Now it is declaration of a function.

Comment: https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es23-prefer-the--initializer-sy
That's the reason why the prefered way of initilization is {}